# All X-axis labels not showing up for null values of Y-axis in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

My SQL server query has this output:
Period_Code PeriodName  NRRI    Depleted    RvCR    ARRI
201401  Jan 90  100 101 98
201402  Feb 101 100 110 101
201403  Mar 97  100 92  97
201404  Apr 88  100 92  NULL
201405  May 88  100 102 NULL
201406  Jun NULL    100 NULL    NULL
201407  Jul NULL    100 NULL    NULL
201408  Aug NULL    100 NULL    NULL
201409  Sep NULL    100 NULL    NULL
201410  Oct NULL    100 NULL    NULL
201411  Nov NULL    100 NULL    NULL

The report is a line chart having x-axis labels as PeriodName i.e. Jan, Feb, etc.
The y-axis has numerical values NRRI, Depleted, RvCR, ARRI.
When preview is clicked, the chart is showing x-axis labels from Jan to Jun.
The category group in the chart is PeriodName but sorting is done by Period_Code.
Please help how to show x-axis labels from Jan to Nov inspite of NULL values of y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Right click on the horizontal axis labels and select Horizontal Axis Properties. On the properties dialog select the Axis Options then set the Interval Type field to Months.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However,interval type to months didn't solve the problem. I have set interval = 1 and interval_type = auto in horizontal axis properties, then only all months Jan, Feb, Mar are coming but till June. Further June, nothing comes up.

Comment: Having NULL Values on the chart should be the same as having a Y value as far as the X axis labels go. Just out of curiosity, what happens when you extend the width of the chart?

Comment: Changing the width didnot help.

Comment: I had a problem like this a while back and it had to do with the chart being in a table and the last couple of axis labels would not push out because the chart was using the design time width of the table at runtime or something.

Comment: Hi LRB, my chart is not in a table. It is pasted in report body.